Checkout of commit after "git log -S" does not contain sought string
I have found commit theoretically containing sought string:
git log -S "example_string"

This gives me commit hash, I check it out, get message about "detached head", but example_string is NOT present in any of the files.
What's going on?

Commits found by your log command contain said string in their changeset (which, in git, is infered from commited states), but it's also the case when said string is deleted rather than added. It could explain its absence in your commit. To be checked. Add --name-status to your log to find out, deletions are prefixed with D.

@RomainValeri It turned out smth else happened: the string has shown up only after I explicitly checked out modified file from that commit (git checkout <hash> -- path_to_modded_file). But your comment led me down the right path by checking status and seeing what file was modified.

@LetMeSOThat4U If the problem is solved then please either answer the question yourself, accept an existing right answer, or delete the question. Don't leave it hanging open if help is no longer needed.

It may be because
a) you are checking out the same commit where the string is being removed (or) checked out to a previous commit
adding -p will check the surrounding commits for this string like
git log -p -S "example_string"

b) the file may have been renamed, to check this add a --follow flag
git log --follow -p -S "example_string" <paht_to_file>

